# acf() function "lag.max" parameter explanation

Tags: r, time-series

I am using the `acf` function in Time Series Analysis and have confusion understanding the `lag.max` argument in it.

The help for the function gives the following explanation for `lag.max`-

> lag.max: maximum lag at which to calculate the acf.  Default is
>             10*log10(N/m) where N is the number of observations and m the
>             number of series.  Will be automatically limited to one less
>             than the number of observations in the series.

What's `m` or the number of series?

Say I have a time series having monthyl data for the past 34 months and I need to make a prediction for the next month (or the 35th month).

In this case `N` will be 34, but what should be `m` so that I can calculate "lag.max" parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

m is the dimension of your data. So it just matters if you have a multidimensional time series. In your case, as I understand from your question, m=1.

```
N<-200
a<-1:N
b<-1:N

acf(a)
# m=1
# lag.max = 10*log10(N/1) = 23"

df<-data.frame(a,b)
acf(df)
# m=2
# lag.max = 10*log10(N/2) = 20"
```

Comment: My dataset has 6 columns and 2935849 number of rows. What should I take 'm' in this case? m = 6 ? Using the formula, is my calculation correct for "lag.max" = 10*log10*(2935849 / 6) = 56.89582 ?

Comment: That depends on whether you want to investigate the auto-correlation of only one variable or the cross-correlation of several variables. m is just the dimension of the argument you feed acf() with. 
However, "lag.max=10*log10(N/m)" is just the default value. You can give lag.max any (positive integer) value you like.

Comment: @Arun, "lag.max" is the maximal lag that will be plotted in the afc output. (not sure if this was clear.)

Comment: it's not really clear. Any place I can read in depth about it as I am new to Time Series Analysis? Thanks!

Comment: So I think your question goes more into the direction of understanding auto-correlation functions in general rather than the R function acf(). In that case any book on linear time series analysis would probably do it.

Comment: If I give m = 2 does that mean that I am calculating the auto-correlation of two variables (this being the case of correlation of 2 variables)? I will try and read linear time series analysis.

Comment: Let me put it like this: If you give the function acf() two time series "a" and "b", (as it is the case of the lower example in my answer), it will calculate and plot the auto-correlation of "a", the auto-correlation of "b" and the cross-correlation of "a" and "b".

Comment: So "m" is basically the number of time series that you are feeding to "acf()" as you replied. For "m" time series, lag.max = 10 * log10(N / m) is the default value.